# Customize fancyhdr in order to get the subject matter of \part

Tags: errors, fancyhdr, parts

I want to get the subject matter of `\part` in the even number page on left by customizing the package `fancyhdr`.

I strongly doubt that it has a package conflict with `babel` french.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} \makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@part}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@spart}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\rightmark}{\parttitle}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\LaTeX}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Stackexchange}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO]{eftpart\l}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Questions}
\part{Ask Question} 
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In the log file, I have this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6     \pretocmd
                 {\@part}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
```

Comment: In general, a Part has many chapters and a Chapter has many sections. Has the Part you put after your Chapter to be considered a section? Or do you want a Part with many chapters? See my answer, if it doesn't solve your problem, please add some more details.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear: the command   `\pretocmd` is not recognized. That happens simply because you didn't load `etoolbox` package.

`babel` has nothing to do with your error.

Moreover, I have changed 
`\fancyfoot[LO]{eftpart\l}` with  `\fancyfoot[LO]{\thepart}` because I think there's something wrong in `eftpart\l` but I don't know what you intended.

By the way, a "Part" contains many chapters, not the contrary (I've inverted the order in your MWE).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} \makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@part}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@spart}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\rightmark}{\parttitle}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\LaTeX}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Stackexchange}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\thepart}

\begin{document}
\part{Question} 
\chapter{Ask Question}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Untested: `\parttitle` is not yet defined until `\part` has been used, so `\rightmark` could fail in case there is content before `\part`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think the OP is confused about Parts and Chapters, let's wait for more details from him...

Comment: Apologize me for his delay. It is \part, I confirm.

Comment: @Zbigniew does my answer solve your problem or you need something different?